# Error while installing tiff-4.0.3

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++, make

I get the following errors while installing tiff-4.0.3:

```
pranav@pranav-Inspiron-1545:~$ cd dependency/
pranav@pranav-Inspiron-1545:~/dependency$ tar -xvf libtiff4-3.6.0-5.tar.bz2 
usr/bin/cygtiff4.dll  

pranav@pranav-Inspiron-1545:~/dependency$ tar -xvf libtiff4-3.6.0-5-src.tar.bz2 
Libtiff is now configured for i686-pc-linux-gnu

  Installation directory:             /usr/local  
  Documentation directory:            ${prefix}/share/doc/tiff-4.0.3  
  C compiler:                         gcc -g -O2 -Wall -W  
  C++ compiler:                       g++ -g -O2  
  Enable runtime linker paths:        no  
  Enable linker symbol versioning:    no  
  Support Microsoft Document Imaging: yes  
  Use win32 IO:                       no  

 Support for internal codecs:  
  CCITT Group 3 & 4 algorithms:       yes  
  Macintosh PackBits algorithm:       yes  
  LZW algorithm:                      yes  
  ThunderScan 4-bit RLE algorithm:    yes  
  NeXT 2-bit RLE algorithm:           yes  
  LogLuv high dynamic range encoding: yes  

 Support for external codecs:  
  ZLIB support:                       yes  
  Pixar log-format algorithm:         yes  
  JPEG support:                       yes  
  Old JPEG support:                   yes  
  JPEG 8/12 bit dual mode:            no  
  ISO JBIG support:                   no  
  LZMA2 support:                      no  

  C++ support:                        yes  

  OpenGL support:                     no  

pranav@pranav-Inspiron-1545:~/dependency/tiff-4.0.3$ make
Making all in port  
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/pranav/dependency/tiff-4.0.3/port'  
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.  
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pranav/dependency/tiff-4.0.3/port'  
Making all in libtiff  
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/pranav/dependency/tiff-4.0.3/libtiff'  
make  all-am  
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/pranav/dependency/tiff-4.0.3/libtiff'  
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -g -O2 -Wall -W -MT tif_jpeg.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tif_jpeg.Tpo -c -o tif_jpeg.lo tif_jpeg.c  
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -g -O2 -Wall -W -MT tif_jpeg.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tif_jpeg.Tpo -c tif_jpeg.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/tif_jpeg.o  
In file included from /usr/local/include/jpeglib.h:27:0,  
                 from tif_jpeg.c:88:  
/usr/local/include/jmorecfg.h:263:16: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
**make[2]: *** [tif_jpeg.lo] Error 1  **
**make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pranav/dependency/tiff-4.0.3/libtiff'  **  
**make[1]: *** [all] Error 2**  
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pranav/dependency/tiff-4.0.3/libtiff'  
**make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1  **
```

How do I get rid of these errors?

Comment: Duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172387/error-while-installing-tiff-3-8-2)

Answer (score 3):

The version of libtiff4 that you are trying to install is no longer supported by Ubuntu, however newer versions of libtiff4 are available. A list of the versions of libtiff4 that are available for all versions of Ubuntu, sorted by Ubuntu release names, can be found [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libtiff4&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

You can find the version of libtiff4 that matches your system by opening the Ubuntu Software Center and typing "libtiff4" in the search box.

In Ubuntu 14.04-20.04 the libtiff4 package has been replaced by libtiff5.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef enum { FALSE= 0, TRUE= 1 } boolean;
```

this does not work for me. however, this works:

```
//typedef enum { FALSE= 0, TRUE= 1 } boolean;
#define boolean bool
```

yup, ugly, but at least it compiles.

Answer (score -1):

Just edit the file `/usr/local/include/jmorecfg.h` at line 263 and replace the space 
before the `=` sign.

Change

```
typedef enum { FALSE = 0, TRUE = 1 } boolean;
```

to

```
typedef enum { FALSE= 0, TRUE= 1 } boolean;
```